# SQL Query Across Three Tables

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to query across three tables and find a certain result.

**directory**
String playerid, String college, int year

**playersSchools**
String playerid, String schoolID

**salaries**
String playerid, int salary, int year

I am trying to join these tables to find out which colleges produce the highest paying players.  directory gives the ID for the school, while playersSchools gives the name of the college and the players graduating year.  This is what I have right now that is not working, I am still a novice at SQL and trying to get better.

```
SELECT a.salary, b.college, c.playerid, d.graduatingyear 
FROM
salaries as a
inner join directory as b on a.playerid=b.playerid
inner join playersschools as c on b.playerid=c.playerid
where 
a.salary > 500000
sort by
a.salary
```

Thank you!

Some example data in my tables:

**directory**

- String Playerid: "ahron01", "tomv19", "samh25"
- String College: "wvu", "psu", "su"
- int year: 1956, 1978, 1990

**playersSchools**

- String Playerid: "ahron01", "tomv19", "samh25"
- String SchoolID: "wvu", "psu", "su"
- int graduatingyear: 1995, 2000, 2002

**salaries**

- String Playerid: "ahron01", "tomv19", "samh25"
- int salary: "500000", "4580000", "1000000"
- int year: 1956, 1986, 2000

So what i would like to get as a result would be an ordered list like:

playerid, college, salary, graduatingyear
"ahron01", wvu, $500,000, 1956

And then I would sort by the highest paying and what college.  I am trying to see which colleges produce the highest paid players, and print their graduating year as well.

Thanks!

Comment: please write an example of what you have in tables and the result you want.

Comment: better even create a http://sqlfiddle.com/ with your data

Comment: and also do u want to have result year wise?

Comment: it seems to me that the *directory* table does in fact **not** contain playerid, but maybe schoolId

Comment: "colleges produce the highest paying players" is not clear. What do you want to find out exactly? Do you want to find the player that pays most? Or the top paying player from each college? Or something else?

Comment: I adjusted the original question, sorry i was too vague!

Comment: What SQL implementation are you using?

Comment: I'm actually using TEIID to query across multiple sources, but just SQL-92 works perfectly.

Comment: your table design is really a bit... umm... confusing. why repeat the info about a player being in a college in both tables directory and playersSchools? and why naming the school once schoolId and once college?

Comment: I know, its not very practical.  I am just trying to learn more SQL.  It could definitely be more efficient in terms of table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by this Query you will get first player wich is paid highest salary

you can add where condition for more filter...

```
SELECT top 1 a.salary, b.college, c.playerid 
FROM
salaries as a
inner join directory as b on a.playerid=b.playerid
inner join playersschools as c on b.playerid=c.playerid

sort by
a.salary desc
```

Comment: Thank you Javal!  This has me rolling!